# ORA-01762, sub-query in select

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have a very huge statement and during the execution, I am always getting this error:

> ORACLE - ORA-01762: vopdrv: view query block not in FROM.

It seems like it is an internal error and my only chance is trying to rewrite my statement.

My statement looks like this:

```
Select column1, column2, (Select CASE WHEN ......A.column=..., B.column=..)
FROM
Table1, (Select ...) A, (Select...) B
```

So I have a select-query in my Select Statement which references columns in the from part. This error goes away If I remove the subquery in my select-statement, however I don't know how to exactly rewrite it. I have tried to move it in the from-part, however I cannot reference other tables like A or B. I am not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need the second select:

```
Select column1, column2, (CASE WHEN ......A.column=..., B.column=..)...
```